# Adding a map area to a MemorySteam Image in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core-mvc, memorystream, asp.net-core-7.0

Using Visual Studio 2022 - I have the following view:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GenerateImage","Position", new imageID = (int)TempData.Peek("image")})' alt="A Landscape Image" style="width:95%;height=75%" usemap"#TestMap" />
<map name="TestMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="100,100,1000,1000" style="cursor: pointer" alt="A Closeup Image" target="_blank" href='@Url.Action("ZoomIn", "Position")' />
</map>
```

In the position controller, `GenerateImage(int imageID)` pulls a generic jpg, adds some images on top of it, then writes it out to the memory stream:

```
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    OverviewMap.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    result = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/jpeg");  
}

return result;
```

However, the displayed image has no active map area. I assume it's because the image came from the memory stream rather than a physical image.

What I am trying to do is to make the images I added on top of the base image clickable that will open to a new tab so that I can provide more in depth information.

My first thought was to use an image map on the loaded image. I've also thought about adding a transparent image on top of the first image with the mapping to the transparent image, or just adding a mouse click event.

I'm sure there are ways to do all of the above. My preference would probably be using a mouse event if possible, as I can make use of it later in the project.

Comment: no, I don't think the described issue relates to the file generation, or content, and persisting. You're seeing the image with no heatmap, right? the heatmap functionality and behavior would be a control/element in scope here.  Is it possible that this typo `usemap"#TestMap"` is the cause?

Comment: excuse me, I meant to say 'image map'.

Comment: LOL, wow, now I feel dumb for not seeing that.  No wonder I couldn't find anything with a google search on how to get this working.  Thanks Brett!

Comment: no problem, I'll put this observation in an answer form so we can find closure to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Given that

> the displayed image has no active map area.

You're providing a source image and it is displaying. The scope of this issue with image map not existing -- nor being eventful -- lyes in the html control markup.

In the markup snippet you provided, `usemap"#TestMap"` is not valid -- and it **may not be** interpreted (nor corrected) by the user-agent/browser.

Try doing,
`usemap="#TestMap"`